# Why doesn't the TinyMCE editor appear on my web application?

Tags: jsp, netbeans, struts, tinymce

I'm making a web application in Struts using the NetBeans IDE. I want the TinyMCE editor to appear on my index.jsp. I already downloaded the necessary files and located them in the following path:

...\NetBeansProjects\BlogStruts\src\java\tinymce\jscripts\tiny_mce ... [lots of files here]

Now, my **index.jsp** file is this:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "textareas"
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <textarea name="content" cols="50" rows="15">
                 This is some content that will be editable with TinyMCE.
         </textarea>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I run the application, index.jsp only contains a textarea with "This is some content that will be editable with TinyMCE." inside it. I can't see any of the TinyMCE features.

I couldn't find the solution anywhere else. Some people seem to have the same problem but they didn't get a response. Already read the FAQs in http://www.tinymce.com/ followed like 10 different tutorials with no luck.

What am I doing wrong? Am I loading the script correctly? Thanks.

Comment: try using an absolute path for tiny_mce.js instead of the relative one (just to see if that solves the issue)

Comment: That would be ...\NetBeansProjects\BlogStruts\sr'c\java\tinymce\jscripts\tiny_mce\jscripts\tiny_mce\tiny_mce.js ?

Comment: nonono, just enter the location available over the web there like "http://myserver.com/my files/tinymce_js_script/tinymce.js"

Answer (score 0):

tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "textareas"
});

Comment: It wasn't a mistake on my code, it was my mistake when I put the code here. I'll edit it. Thanks

Comment: try putting it at the bottom of the document or in a document ready function

Comment: Are you running on local machine? If so.... there is an error message in the demo stating: The examples might not work properly on the local file system due to security settings in your browser. Please use a real webserver.